# Returning a value from a method within a lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to figure out how to return a method value from a lambda expression:

```
public int findMissingNumber(Collection<Integer> ints) {
    Single<Integer> start = new Single<>(1);
    ints.stream().mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).parallel().forEach(i -> {
        if (i != start.setValue(start.getValue() + 1)) {
            //return here
        }
    });
    return -1;
}
```

However, it seems that using the `return` keyword in the lambda expression will explicitly return to the lambda function itself. Is there some type of way to break or force a return for the entire method?

Comment: What do you wish to return? If you are returning a member of the stream that fulfills some condition, use a filter.

Comment: @Eran if you're not returning a member of the stream and need to return a derived value, then see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75622699/1852005

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Is there some type of way to break or force a return for the entire method?

No. At least, not unless you throw an exception.

Basically, that's not what `forEach` is meant for. You could write a method which accepted a function which would return `null` for "keep going" and non-null for "stop, and make this the result"... but that method *isn't* `forEach`.

The fact that you're using a lambda expression is really incidental here. Imagine you were just calling `forEach` and passing in some argument - wouldn't it be *really* weird if that call made your `findMissingNumber` method return (without an exception), without the `findMissingNumber` method itself having the return statement?

Comment: I suppose the main reason I was using `forEach` and streams to start would be the use of `parallel` (as this is going through a large collection). Would you be able to expand upon the "how" of making a method/function for going through a stream like that?

Comment: @Rogue: Well, you could quite possibly build it with `filter()` and `findFirst()` - make your `filter` predicate only return the items that "match", and then find the first element of that stream. On the other hand, your lambda expression currently has a side effect (`start.setValue()`) which isn't a good starting point for parallelization...

Comment: That seems to make it clean enough, though I suppose it's a little disheartening there's not a way to halt by the first found occurrence (throwing an exception doesn't seem to escape the lambda either). Thanks!

Comment: @Rogue: Well, `filter(...).findFirst()` *does* halt at the first found occurrence...

Comment: Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24719306/1441122) for an example using `filter` and `findFirst` and some additional discussion.

Comment: In Ruby, IIRC, (x) -> { return } jumps out of the calling function, not the lambda block. That makes some algorithms really lean and efficient to code

Answer (score 14):

(Is this an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?)

The question is about how to return from a lambda inside a `forEach`. [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24704840/1441122) provided some useful information about `findFirst` and also cautioned about side effects in a lambda run in parallel -- both excellent points.

But regarding the original question, I'm still thinking: what problem are you trying to solve?

The method name `findMissingNumber` in the example is suggestive. The method takes a collection of numbers as a parameter and iterates over it while incrementing a counter. It returns when it finds a mismatch, or it returns -1 if there is no mismatch. Since the counter is incremented once as each value in the `ints` collection is processed, it seems like that collection is expected to be in order, unless a number is missing.

If so, the parameter ought to be a `List` instead of a `Collection`. (Making a big assumption here.) Under this assumption, one could rewrite the code using lambdas as streams like so:

```
static OptionalInt findMissingNumber(List<Integer> ints) {
    return
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, ints.size())
            .filter(i -> i != ints.get(i-1))
            .findFirst();
}
```

Instead of incrementing a counter, we use `IntStream.range` to generate the values expected to be in the list. We then rely on random access to the list to `get` values from their expected positions in the list. We filter for the mismatches and return the first one, if any. This avoids mutation and so should run correctly in parallel. (Note that this doesn't parallelize well if the list isn't random-access, though.)

The return value is an `OptionalInt` which is *empty* if no mismatch was found. This is more explicit than using a sentinel value like `-1` to indicate the "not found" condition.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers describe the best approach if you want to maintain performance through parallel thread execution (e.g. using `filter(...).findFirst()`). However if:

1. Performance is not of concern

   - and therefore serial loop execution is acceptable
2. You want to return early out of a loop

   - and the *type* you want to return is *different* from the type you're iterating over (e.g. `String` in the below example)

Then `filter(...).findFirst()` is not an option for you, because it must return one of the values in the collection you're iterating over.

In this case, you can opt for the following kind of approach:

```java
public String findMissingNumber(Collection<Integer> ints) {
    for (var i : ints) {
        if (true) {
            return "someCalculatedReturnValue";
        }
    };
    return "noneFound";
}
```

Comment: It's a bit of an old question, but `ints.stream().filter(i -> true).findFirst().map(i -> "someReturnValue").orElse("noneFound");` would be the stream equivalent to your example. Streams are still an option, I just asked this question before having as firm a grasp on lambdas.

Comment: Ah that's true @Rogue. My case is different because I'm actually looping over Objects, and my `if (true)` is actually `if (matcher.find()) {` then return `matcher.group()`. It's *possible* to use streams, but I'd have to repeat the `Pattern`/`Matcher` logic in both the `filter` and the `map` which isn't ideal, so just wanted to post this as an alternative early-out option.

Comment: What you can do in that case is a `#map` call, returning either `matcher.group()` or `null` if `#find` was `false`. Then you'd `.filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst()`, et voila! Of course, don't feel like you have to use streams if a vanilla loop will solve your problems.

Comment: @Rogue you are spot on! I must say, the final code is less intuitive - it's not clearly an early-out, so I'll leave the above answer as-is. But yes, since Streams exit as early as possible, this is functionally equivalent to an early-out, but parallelizable too! Thanks for the follow-up.